# Ripple effect /click animation with LiveData

Tags: android, animation, click, android-livedata, ripple

I have items in LinearLayout. Items open other activity when I clicked. Ripple effect appears when I clicked list item. But a list item is LiveData and ripple effect can't appear on this item. Because ripple effect needs little time to appear and LiveData is fast. What can I do?

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:foreground="@drawable/clicked">
```

clicked.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I use these codes instead of ripple.

```
android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
```

or

```
android:background="@drawable/on_press_animation"
```

on_press_animation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
```